# What's the point of having a Main class in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, program-entry-point

I have come across examples where people used a `Main` class, and from there, inside the `Main` class, write logic that instantiates other classes and calls their functions.

Example:

```
# ^^^ code containing class OtherClass() ^^^

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        print("\n **** Main class from which we call other classes **** \n")

        other_object = OtherClass()
        
        self.plot_graphs(other_object)

        
    def plot_graphs(self, other_object):
        # plot stuff
        pass

# vvv code containing main code which instantiates main = Main() vvv
```

Upon implementing this, I see warnings that all of my methods/functions in the `Main` class (like `plot_graphs`) are/should be static. In that sense, why have a `Main` class at all if you could just as well take out those functions outside of the `Main`?

I know that there are workarounds like adding a decorator like `@staticmethod` or a macro like `#noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic`. But this got me wondering whether it is Pythonic at all to have a `Main` class if you don't alter it's attributes, or not.

Answer (score 5):

#### There is no point. You're looking at code written by a Java programmer who never bothered to learn Python idioms.

Idiomatic Python scripts will have a `main` *function*, but not some top-level class wrapping it. A standard structure would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# imports here

# Globals (usually constants) here

# Non-main functions & classes (possibly for use when imported as a module) here

def main():
    # Parse arguments and do main script things here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The Java developer who wrote the code you're looking at is used to Java, where *everything* must be part of a class (and for that matter, a given source file can have only one public top-level class, so the entry point for a Java program typically sits alone, and relies on utility classes from other files). In Python, the module itself it executable. Even if you needed some class-like behaviors, the module itself acts like one for most basic use cases (e.g. global variables handle the job of instance attributes). About the only conceivable use for such a class would be if you were going to run several executions of the entry point in parallel and wanted them each to have their own separate "globals", but the contortions you'd need to go through, in which you want to do that and simpler functions don't handle the job adequately, would be painful.

Technically, you don't need `main` or `if __name__ == '__main__':` for simple scripts that are never imported as modules, but it's a good idea to get in the habit, because some things, e.g. the `multiprocessing` module running in non-`fork` mode, assume the main module can be imported to establish state matching the parent process; if you haven't guarded the "script" behaviors properly, they'll get rerun in *every* worker.

---

Strictly speaking, the contents of the `main` function don't need to be in a function; you *could* just inline them within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. The advantages to putting them in a dedicated function are:

1. Namespace separation between "script" stuff and "module" stuff. If you don't wrap the script behaviors in a function, you pollute the global namespace, and you may accidentally *rely* on those global names for the utility functions. When you later try to import the module into another script, those variables aren't defined, and the utility functions don't work
2. Performance: When run at global scope, all variables are globally scoped, which, on CPython, means loading or storing to them involves a `dict` operation. Doing the same work inside a function with locally scoped variables reduces it to a C level array lookup. While both are average case `O(1)`, `dict` operations have greater variability and higher fixed overhead than directly loading from a C array.

Comment: The ability to import a module without running arbitrary code is also important for test frameworks.

Comment: @chepner: Yar. There's a number of cases where something that is logically "just a script", not *intended* as an importable module, still gets imported in non-`__main__` mode. Most of them are not going to be introduced to beginners for a while, so all I can really tell them is "trust me, if you don't use `if __name__ == '__main__':` guards for your script behaviors, you'll eventually regret it". Much like I tell them to use raw strings for *all* regexes and Windows paths, and use `argparse` over `sys.argv` for argument parsing. They rarely listen, but I get to say "I told you so" later. :-)

Comment: Agreed; I just figured testing pops up more often than parallel processing :)

Comment: @chepner: Pfffttt... Who tests their code? If it doesn't die with a `SyntaxError`, it's good. ;-)